# How to replace or manipulate the Microsoft Desktop Window Manager (DWM)?

Tags: windows, user-interface

I'm in the midst of deciding which platform to use to implement a new kind of display server / window manager. It seems that it isn't possible to replace the DWM on Windows systems according to [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848042(v=vs.85).aspx).

But then, how do folks go about doing fancy 3d stuff like [this video of a 3d window manager framework for the DWM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_6Fuyu4l_E) without resorting to [hacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fpvh16VjrRE) like [this](https://github.com/steeve/dwmaxx2).

For example, in the Linux world we can configure the OS to use entirely different window managers (eg. Enlightenment, Compiz, KWin) and entirely different desktop environments (eg. KDE, Gnome).

How might one go about truly "swapping in" different window managers / desktop environments on the Windows platform, getting access to the buffers that applications draw to, being able to control and delegate user interface events, etc.?

Comment: what project / technology to take up next is explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6486/40980

Comment: @gnat Dude this question doesn't ask folks about what choice to make; it specifically asks _how_ to manipulate the DWM.

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: I'm asking _how_ to do it, not _is it possible_?

Comment: "Is it possible to replace the DWM on Windows systems?"

Comment: I suspect that's an application that simulates a window manager, running as an additional layer.  The youtube video says it runs inside the DWM.

Comment: is there any reason you didn't look at open source window managers for windows? here's one: http://sourceforge.net/p/bb4win/code/HEAD/tree/ - I don't frankly know how it's done off hand but I'm sure there's plenty of resources around google that talk about it because there's been lots of applications that did it